# ember not communicating with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ember.js

I am following the tutorial at [**Ember and Rails 5 with JSON API: A Modern Bridge**](https://emberigniter.com/modern-bridge-ember-and-rails-5-with-json-api/).

Thus, I now have a rails-api for backend and ember for front end. I started the rails server as suggested:

> $ bin/rails server --binding 0.0.0.0

Started the ember server:

> $ Ember s --proxy --http ://localhost:8080 --port 8081

I had to specify a port for creating the Ember server though, because I got an error saying:

> Port 8080 is already in use

It seems as the rails backend work as if it is suppose to. When I visited http://localhost/something.json I get the proper json response.

In the tutorial they ask you to visit the ember frontend open ember inspector, console and enter the command :

> $E.store.findAll('book');

The response I get is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'findAll' of undefined(…)

I am using c9 with this tutorial, not sure if it has anything to do with it though.

The question is, Why am I getting this Error?

I Am new to stackoverflow, Rails and Ember.

I have searched the question and the solutions posted did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

To access the store, you have to use getters.

Like:

```
this.get('store').findAll('book');
```

Because the store is a service and lazy-loaded.